# mergesort complexity O(nlogn) + O(n)?

Tags: time-complexity, mergesort

When analyzing the time complexity of the merge sort, I know that since there are O(log(n)) levels and each level takes a O(n) operation, the entire time complexity should be O(nlog(n)).

However, doesn't dividing take O(n) total? Each dividing of the set of elements take O(1) but you divide a total of O(n) times so doesn't the dividing part of the merge sort take O(n)? For example, if you have 8 elements, you have to divide 7 times and if you have 16 elements, you have to divide 15 times.

So, shouldn't the entire merge sort time complexity technically be O(nlog(n))+O(n)? I know that O(nlog(n) + n) is the same thing as O(nlog(n)) but no one seems to mention this in the explanation of the merge sort time complexity.

Comment: You know they are the same, but don't understand why no one says so?

Comment: I'm just thinking that my logic behind the deletion process being O(n) may be flawed since I can't see anywhere about the deletion part being O(n) but ultimately being ignored at the end.

Comment: That isn't what you asked; you asked why an O(n) term was ignored for an O(n log n) algorithm, and it's the same reason any sub-O(n log n) (for example, O(1)) is ignored, as others have explained and you claim to already understand.

Answer (score 2):

O(*n* log *n* + *n*) is the same thing as O(*n* log *n*). *n* log *n* grows faster than *n*, so the *n* term is extraneous.